# PN53x with emulate nfc

Tags: rfid, nfc, chip-design, iso14443, emulation

I saw that many of nfc reader/emulate based on [PN53x chipset](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=PN53x) of NXP.

But the disadvantage of this chipset is , you can't emulate `ISO14443-B`

1. why is PN53x chipset can't do it? what is so special on this iso?
2. i looking for another nfc reader that can emulate this iso
3. why many of nfc reader based on this chipset?

Comment: 1) Why says ISO14443-B is special? Perhaps the PN53x series was designed before ISO14443-B was defined. 2) that's a shopping question, that's off-topic here, you'll have to find a reader yourself 3) There can be many reasons: it just works, perhaps it was the first solution, NXP provides the tags so for compatibility also use NXP reader chips, perhaps it is the cheapest. Explain why an NFC reader should not be based on this chip.

Answer (score 0):

> why is PN53x chipset can't do it? what is so special on this iso?

ISO14443-B is the only standard among the NFC chips that use BPSK encoding. Also ISO14443-B is not used much in practice. Maybe NXP decided that it's not worth implementing a mode that only a few people would use.

> i looking for another nfc reader that can emulate this iso

As far as I know all modern NFC controllers aimed for the mobile market can do this. The need for B card-mode came with the idea of having your credit-card in your mobile phone.

> why many of nfc reader based on this chipset?

The PN53x chips are cheap and *very* easy to integrate. You can just hook it up to a usb-serial converter (for the very common PN532) or directly connect it to USB (PN533). That's all you need for a USB based NFC reader.

The newer chips have a more complex host interface and require an additional micro-controller to act as a bridge between USB and the reader-chip itself. Their advantage is a much tighter control over the timing. This is very important in the credit-card reader market.

Comment: thank about you reply.
1.do you know some simple nfc-device i can connect to my android and emulate 14443b?

   2. by the way. the limitation of emulte castum uid and not random uid is the reader device limit? is there device that allow to do it?

3. the credit card working with 14443b ?

Comment: @paw24068-loaoa.com 1: No idea. 2: fixed UID is likely a software limitation. The reader-chips don't care. 3. Yes, there are a few ISO14443b credit-cards out there.  The majority is A though.

Comment: about 2. that intresting because on the link i gave you can see that on ISO14443-3 you can emulate only uid that start with 0x08.     by thw way 14443b(with BPSK encoding like sri 512) as i know is nfc type 4,